# Need help adding WordPress shortcode to my css page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, shortcode

```
#investment-focus-hero .jumbotron {
    background: /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ linear-gradient( rgba(255 , 255, 255, 0.05), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)), /* bottom, image */ url('<?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="jumbotron_full_image" post_id="237"]'); ?>');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 37.42%;
}
```

Comment: When I add <?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="jumbotron_full_image" post_id="237"]'); ?> to my css page, It does not render.

Comment: If you are trying to add shortcode in css file it will never work what you need to do is to create a style.php file to generate dynamic css and include this in your functions.php file using `require_once(includes/style.php)`(considering you place your style.php file in 'includes' folder within your active theme).

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension of the file to php, then update your link tag's file path where you load in the CSS file in your header.

So your link tag would go from this:

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

To this:

```
<link href="css/styles.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This way the CSS gets run by the server!